# Iconos en explorador de Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, ide

¿Qué extensión es la que muestra los iconos con diferentes formas y colores en las carpetas y archivos del explorador de la izquierda en Visual Studio?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es visual studio, es VSCode creo que ahi está asi por defecto

Answer (score 0):

Vale ya he encontrado lo que quería para resolver mi problema.
La extensión que quería para VSCode es una que se llama "VSCode simpler Icons with Angular". Es justamente para un proyecto de Angular con el que estoy.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.